# How to change form layouts in Django 1.8

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a form

```
Field Name: [Input Box]
```

I want

```
Field Name:
[Input Box]
```

How can I achieve this?

forms.py

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
form = SearchForm()
html_dtc = {'form':form}
return render_to_response('site/home.html', html_dtc)
```

home.html

```
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update</button>
</form>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a custom form rendering. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually). For example, the following code would achieve what you're after.

```
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} <br/>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update</button>
</form>
```

(`field.errors` are added, because when you are manually rendering the form, you have to take care of error rendering as well)

Comment: looks like we have a winner

Answer (score 3):

Try to overide form.as_p()

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   search = forms.CharField()

   def as_p(self):
    "Returns this form rendered as HTML <p>s."
     return self._html_output(
        normal_row='<p%(html_class_attr)s>%(label)s <br> %(field)s%(help_text)s</p>',
        error_row='%s',
        row_ender='</p>',
        help_text_html=' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one off thing you can render your form manually like described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) in the documentation.

Otherwise there's the [django-floppyforms](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) which gives you great control over how forms and (default) widgets are rendered.
Just define a [custom layout](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/stable/layouts.html#create-custom-layouts), make it the default, use floppyforms custom Form classes (they behave exactly the same) and you're good to go.

As far as I remember some of floppyforms's functionality will also be included in Django 1.9, so look out for that, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use `django_crispy_forms`: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

In the template include `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` and for the form:

```
{% crispy form %}
```

In addition, you can change the layout of the form easily, by overriding the `form_class` in the init function of the form:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal' # <-- leave out for vertical, or form-inline
        self.helper.render_hidden_fields = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(InlineRadios('applying_for_whom'), css_class="col-xs-12"),
            Div(InlineRadios('gender'), css_class='col-xs-12'),
            Div('agreed_to_data_transmit', css_class="col-xs-12"),
```

As a bonus, if you are using bootstrap, set also set `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'` so then everything is taken care of automatically for vertical bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Field Name:</label>
    {{ form.search }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Update</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

generally I don't recommend use the HTML code generated by Django, but instead I supply what is needed by the DJANGO form.

but some are required: like the ERRORs, like the CSRF token.

let me add some examples to clarify what I am talking

```
<form class="*" style="*">
    <label /><input name="email" />
    <label /><input name="password" />
<form>
```

basically what I am suggesting is, do not use template tags unless absolute necessary like **CSRF**.

in this way, you can completely separate the design from the backend logic. you can have front end work indecently on the UI. the interface is the form fields, you have to supply all fields to the backend. like in this case 'email' && 'password' is required at backend

Comment: @derrend, I added some details. hope it helps.